# How to get resultant HTML after executing all scripts?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

How to get effective HTML after executing all scripts?
Actually scripts are adding and modifying control and css in the page. I would like to see html of resultant display as a static page. Is there any way to get this?
**Edit:** Suppose if background image is added using javascript, How can i see in Html OR css? 
Please try to get this before giving answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to use Firefox with the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) extension.

Firebug is an extension for web developers. Among other things, it offers an "HTML panel":

> The HTML panel displays the generated
>   HTML/XML of the currently opened page.
>   It differs from the normal source code
>   view, because it also displays all
>   manipulations on the DOM tree.
>   [...]

A similar solution for MS Internet Explorer would be the [Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=E59C3964-672D-4511-BB3E-2D5E1DB91038&displaylang=en).

Note that both solution are browser-specific. There is no way to get the resultant HTML independent of the browser used, because this HTML only exists in the working memory of the browser (so you cannot, say, sniff it on the network).

Answer (score 1):

Use the firebug plugin for firefox, with it you can 'view generated source'.

Answer (score 1):

This is a javascript approach. Unfortunately, it doesn't work perfect. For example, it doesn't include the contents of textarea's.

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML
```

Another way is selecting everyting (`Ctrl + A`) and choose 'View selection source' from a context menu.

Answer (score 1):

The [Web Developer Toolbar addon for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/) has a 'View Generated Source' button that let's you do that. It's under the 'View Source' Menu of the toolbar.

It presents manipulated document as a static source, like what the "View Source" option does, but with modification by the Javascript.